# Can't find synergy config file on Windows

Tags: windows-7, windows, synergy

I connected everything just fine; both my Windows 7 64bit (server) and Windows 7 32 bit (client) are connected perfectly.

However, I can't tell Synergy which screen is where because I can't find this configuration file everyone is talking about. I looked in the root folder of the application; there is no "ext/synergy.conf" file, so I created one, but that isn't working either. This is kind of frustrating because I think it is the last step.

I have the newest version from the site but it says version unknown in the application. On Windows, it has that cool drag and drop UI to place your screens where you want them, but nothing is working for my mouse or keyboard.

Answer (score 4):

At some point, the config moved to the registry under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Synergy\Synergy`. On Windows 7, it's then loaded into a temporary file under `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Temp`. The file name should show up in the log window.

There's also an option to save the config to a file (which you can then use in lieu of the registry) under the `File` menu.

Note: this is using v1.5.1

Answer (score 2):

On Windows 7 my synergy configuration file is in:

```
\Users\{my-user-name}\Documents\synergy.sgc
```

I had to delete it and restart as the config gui kept crashing when I tried to delete a screen to reconfigure it.

Comment: I tried looking for the config file here - no joy, at least with v1.7.4

Answer (score 0):

If it exists, you can find it with a search from the root of your drive.

That said, with [Synergy 1.4.2 x64](http://synergy.googlecode.com/files/synergy-1.4.2-Windows-x64.exe) I didn't see a `synergy.conf` file accessed (using [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645)) or stored at all.  The config files that it allows you to save have a `.cfg` extension.

Also, see:

> http://synergy-foss.org/pm/projects/synergy/wiki/UserFAQ#Q-How-do-I-configure-the-application

Answer (score 0):

I just found that link and it helped me to get thru my connectivity problem with synergy.

http://synergy2.sourceforge.net/trouble.html

hope it helps you.