# Synergy: How do I get the AltGr key to work with a Windows server and Linux client?

Tags: linux, windows, keyboard, synergy

I'm using Synergy with a Windows 10 server and a Linux client.

## The problem

When I have my keyboard connected to the Linux PC, I get the following key syms (tested using `xev -event keyboard`)

```
When pressing Ctrl:  Control_L
When pressing Alt:   Alt_L
When pressing AltGr: ISO_Level3_Shift
```

But when I have the keyboard connected to my Windows PC and use it on the Linux client through Synergy, I get these key syms:

```
When pressing Ctrl:  Control_L
When pressing Alt:   Alt_L
When pressing AltGr: Control_L
```

Is there any way of getting the AltGr key on the Windows 10 keyboard to trigger `ISO_Level3_Shift` on the Linux client?

---

## What I have tried

#### The `altgr = alt` config workaround

This works when you have a Linux server and a Windows client, but I'm not sure why.

#### The `alt = altgr` config workaround

This works, but I lose access to the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key, which is just as crucial to me as the <kbd>AltGr</kbd> key.

Answer (score 2):

Server: MAC/Linux

Client: Windows

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>q</kbd> = @

Comment: While this may answer the question, it would be a better answer if you could provide some explanation **why** it does so.

Comment: Please give more information to help OP

Comment: @DavidPostill it does so because ctrl+alt is equivalent to altgr on most operating systems.

Answer (score 1):

I am running Synergy server on Windows 10 and client on Kubuntu 16.04.

Synergy version on both platforms: 1.8.8-stable-c30301e

I had the same problem and got it working with the following configuration.

```
section: screens
    <WINDOWS 10 SERVER NAME>:
    altgr = alt
    <KUBUNTU CLIENT NAME>:
    alt = altgr
```

Comment: It'll be nice to say where to place this lines.

Comment: I am sorry to say that after a few years of intermittent issues related to alt-gr I finally gave up and stopped using Synergy. The most relevant info I found is [here](https://superuser.com/questions/268462/cant-find-synergy-config-file-on-windows#829910). Alternatively, try out their [forum](https://symless.com/forums/).